# Merge [laptop-battery] into [battery]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery) x 373

[laptop-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-battery) x 69

I think that instead of having 2 separate tags, questions about laptop batteries should be tagged with [laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop)[battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery) instead of having a special [laptop-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-battery) tag.

I think it would be better to have all the battery-related questions in one tag. Many people use the [battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery) tag for laptop questions anyway.

Can we merge [laptop-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-battery) into [battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery) and synonymize?

Comment: not all [tag:battery] questions are about laptop batteries.  [Changing the battery of a Logitech M705 mouse](http://superuser.com/q/514592)

Comment: @sathya Hm, I dont see why this should affect the OPs suggestion. He just wants to split all [laptop-battery] questions into [laptop]+[battery]. After that he wants to remove [laptop-battery], which I think is a good suggestion. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nixda hm, I read it the other way around- my bad

Comment: +1 Support. People can still search for the intersection of questions tagged with both laptop+battery using the techniques at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there doesn't seem to be a compelling reason *not* to merge, I would go ahead and merge + synonymize.

There's also [battery-life](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) x130 and [rechargeable-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rechargeable-battery) x10 we might want to take a look at.

For the time being, I left [battery-life](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) be.

---

[laptop-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-battery)

```
updating post history, 82 rows affected
updating posts, 67 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 48 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [battery] and [laptop-battery] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym laptop-battery -> battery was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

[rechargeable-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rechargeable-battery)

```
updating post history, 11 rows affected
updating posts, 10 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 5 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [battery] and [rechargeable-battery] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym rechargeable-battery -> battery was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Comment: I think we can also merge `[battery-life]` - what do you think?