# Merge [laptop-repair] into [repair]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) x 247

[laptop-repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-repair) x 81

I think these [laptop-repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-repair) should be merged into [repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) - just like [battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery) and [laptop-battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop-battery) - [(link)](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6097/merge-laptop-battery-into-battery).

Questions about laptop repair can be tagged with [laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop) and [repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair).

I think many users will find having all the questions about laptop repair in one tag useful, but it would be possible to view them by searching for [laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/laptop)[repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, most computers that have batteries are laptops, but not all computers that can be repaired are laptops. We rarely use dual tags to convey specific meaning – we'd rather have one specific tag like `[laptop-repair]` than a composite (`[laptop][repair]`). At least that's the way we've always used tags (`[video-encoding]` instead of `[video][encoding]`, etc)